# what is the time (format) in the survival package?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I want to perform a survival analysis by means of the according [survival](https://rdrr.io/cran/survival/man/Surv.html) package in r.
I wonder about the time in there:

> time
> for right censored data, this is the follow up time. For
> interval data, the first argument is the starting time for the
> interval.

I'm unsure whether I'm using my data correctly. I simply have a number of hours until a device fails, like 100 hours, 120 hours and so on.
Do I need to change or modify something or is it correct as it is? The survival curves look legit but I'm new in this topic, so I would like to ensure my results.

Comment: Look at the examples in the ?coxph help file.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand it'd be simply the amount of time elapsed. In case of a time-dependent cox model, it'd be start and stop (though from my pov this would ultimately also just be a time difference).